# Angular: How do I enable and disable a textbox by clicking a checkbox?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am using Angular and TypeScript, and trying to enable/disable a textbox using a checkbox.

`app.component.html`

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="true" (click)="check_en(value)">
<input type="text" id="text1" disabled>
```

`app.component.ts`

```js
check_en(v1: any){
  if(v1 == true){
    document.getElementById('text1').setAttribute("disabled", "false");                  
  } else {
    document.getElementById('text1').removeAttribute("disabled")    
  }    
}
```

Comment: I'd strongly advise against manipulationg elements direclty. The whole point of Angular is (more or less) to do that for you ;)

Comment: Yes, as jBuchholz says, you have to go through the angular variables. Otherwise, you lose the benefits of the angular. Another thing, you should rather use 'if (v1)' or 'if (v1 === true)'. The first is shorter and the second is stricter.

Answer (score 3):

Try to avoid modifying DOM directly with `document.getElementById` in Angular. You could achieve the same effect with other options.

#### Option 1: Two-way binding to the `ngModel` directive

Controller

```
export class AppComponent  {
  checkboxStatus: any;
  ...
}
```

Template

```html
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checkboxStatus" (click)="check_en(value)">
<input type="text" id="text1" [disabled]="!checkboxStatus">
```

Here we are [two-way binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#basics-of-two-way-binding) the value of the checkbox to the variable `checkboxStatus` using the [`ngModel`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngmodel-two-way-binding) directive.

---

#### Option 2: Template reference variable

Template

```html
<input #inputCheck type="checkbox" (click)="check_en(value)">
<input type="text" id="text1" [disabled]="!inputCheck.checked">
```

Here a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var) `inputCheck` is used to refer to the checkbox within the DOM. Later it's property `checked` is bound to the text input property `disabled` to dynamically set it's value.

Comment: thank for guide me. I am not good with angular. Now I tyr to learn it.

Comment: You could go through the Angular Tutorial here: https://angular.io/tutorial. It introduces some of the basics.

Comment: What does `(click)="check_en(value)"` do?

Comment: @xr280xr: It is the Angular equivalent of JS [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/onclick) attribute. It registers the event handler `check_en(value)` to be triggered when the `click` event is emitted. More info on Angular binding syntax [here](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax#binding-types-and-targets). Also sidenote: it's irrelevant to the solution. It's a carry over from OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

to set `checkbox` checked, you have to `checked=true` and not by `value`.

For Example:

`<input type="checkbox" checked=true (click)="check_en(value)">`