# How to enable a disabled text box on checkbox using angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have a text box which is disabled using simple disabled html tag. I need to enable it when I click checkbox, again I need to disable it when i uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62277274/angular-how-do-i-enable-and-disable-a-textbox-by-clicking-a-checkbox

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular: How do I enable and disable a textbox by clicking a checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62277274/angular-how-do-i-enable-and-disable-a-textbox-by-clicking-a-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    checkValue = false;
    InputDisabled = true;

    ChangeEvent(){
        if(this.checkValue)
        {
          this.InputDisabled = false;
        } else
        {
          this.InputDisabled = true;
        }
      }
```

```html
    <label for="">Add text to destination filename?</label>
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checkValue" (change)="ChangeEvent()" id="flexCheckDefault">
    <label for="">Text</label>
    <input type="text" style="width: 100px;" [disabled]="InputDisabled">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ngModels** in Angular to see enable/disable the button. Also, renember that you can need to create the variable of the ngModel on your **AppComponent**.

I create a test project for you:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-npvbz5?file=src/app/app.component.html